# American English speakers needing subtitles more often

Tags: pronunciation, vocabulary, american-english, russian

I often ask my American English native speaker friends this question:

> When watching a movie in American English, do you turn the subtitles on?

Quite a lot of them say that they always do ("in order to make sure not to miss any details" is the most common justification).

My native language is Russian, and in Russia it is literally unheard of to turn the subtitles on for Russian movies. Everything that is being said is always 100% crystal clear.

Does this phenomenon arise because of how diverse American English can be in its pronunciation and vocabulary in comparison to Russian's?

**Addendum**: can this phenomenon be due to the fact that the connection between American English sounds and individual letters is much looser than it is for Russian sounds and individual letters?

Comment: English has completely messed up vowels, so even the native speakers cannot disambiguate them.

Comment: *"100% crystal clear."* Really? :-) https://youtu.be/lp_xhM0GYbo

Comment: @bytebuster this is a special recording of a fringe dialect, Vologda dialect to be specific, made by linguistic students, not standard Russian.

Comment: I keep subtitles turned on and the sound muted.  For me, it's about multitasking.  I'm usually doing something else at the same time as watching a movie, or whatever, like right now, when I'm using my laptop.  An occasional glance at the screen is enough to keep track of the action, but having the sound turned on is too distracting.

Comment: @Anixx:  sorry, that is a completely ridiculous claim.  English-speaking children routinely disambiguate vowels. the only time I ever have trouble disambiguation vowels is when talking to a non-native speaker who has not mastered English pronumciation.

Comment: Do you mean Americans turning on captions for American speaking programs? That just seems crazy. It is very rare on American TV to have even the slightest accent (any such accent stands out considerably).

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that this is not a matter of the language, but rather of the sound quality.
Most films come with the original audio in (American) English where the actors speak right during the acting into the microphone placed somewhere in the background at the set. Synchronisations in other languages, however, are recorded in a studio where the synchronisers speak directly into a professional speech microphone. Additionally the speakers focus solely on pronounciation, often making numerous attempts until they reach perfection - as opposed to the actors who mainly need to pay attention to their acting, where crystal-clear speaking is only secondary. The combination of these aspects makes the speech quality in the synchronised audio noticeably better.
You can actually hear the difference if you switch between different language tracks during a film. The speech in the original audio track is always of slightly lower quality than in the synchronised tracks.
It might be interesting to compare the perceived clearness in an originally Russian film with the English synchronisation - I wouldn't be surprised if the tables were turned then.

If it was not about the speech quality of the movie audio, but about the language itself, the apparent understanding difficulty should not be restricted to watching films but extend to everyday communication in American English, i.e. A.E. speakers would generally have more difficulty flawlessly understanding their native language than Russian speakers do. I don't think that this is the case.

Comment: No. In Russian there are films recorded using both technologies, in those which recorded during play the sound even seems better (it reflects all sounds in the action like glasses put on the table etc). There is no difference in intelligibility. It is shocking that some films may be unintelligible to a native speaker whatever the quality of recording.

Comment: I'm a 60-something Brit, so very familiar with American speech, but watching something like The Wire would be impossible without subtitles. Thru a combination of slightly poor hearing, specialized vocabulary and realistically-fuzzy sound in many scenes. But even when I'm watching a British drama or comedy, I prefer subtitles on.

Comment: @David Garner this is fascinating! After tens of years of learning English, I am still unable to understand news and movies, not to say music and I thought it was my specific problem. But if even the native speakers do need subtitles... I have no words. I cannot imagine a Russian movie with however special vocabulary or invented words or bad sound to need subtitles.

Comment: @Anixx, I must stress that doesn't apply to *all* native speakers.

Comment: @David Garner even if to some, it is very fascinating. Never heard and cannot even imagine similar practice in Russian. Is it the reason why the English speakers defend their non-phonetic weird spelling, because this weird spelling allows disambiguate words that you cannot disambiguate in speech?

Comment: I completely agree with user Anixx on every point. I've made an addendum; please, take a look.

Comment: @user376034 Your idea that the asymmetry between spoken and written English supports disambiguation is interesting, but doesn't explain why Russian speech appears to its native speakers as "crystal clear", rather than being perceived *more poorly* because the narrow letter-to-sound correspondence isn't of much help when the audio is unintelligible - but apparently it is not unintelligible.

Comment: @David Garner: I haven't seen the Wire (tho my sister who lived in B'more at the time tells me it's the best ever) but I'm willing to bet much of the dialog is in dialect.  AE, like British English, comes in many dialects.  I've met foreigners who have mastered "standard" AE but have trouble with "Balck" English.  I cannot understand a single word of "Train Spotters", and often have trouble with UK movies in standard dialects, especially if the characters talk fast.  (as a late 50s-ish person w/o a TV I often watch movies at my corner bar, sound off, subtitles on!)

Comment: @lemontree English has a lot of similar-sounding word, moreover, words that differ only in a vowel, while vowels are a mess in English: here, hair,  hare, hear, hire; bet, beat, bat, bait, but, boot, bite etc. Thus the English speakers seem to need to disambiguate. Also there is some culture of omitting consonants, such as speaking "Mars" as "m-a-a", insurance as "i-sh-e-e" (i heard it myself and the police officer repeated it several times the same, I do not know how I figured out what he meant). In Russian it is impossible

Comment: An important side note. In Russian (and Soviet) cinematography and on national television (so called "federal channels") regional accents are practically non-existent. **Anyone with such a regional accent will be mocked at.**

Comment: @mobileink, although there *is* a lot of dialect, that doesn't seem to be a problem, to me at least, possibly because we Brits are so tuned into lots of variations just within the UK, as well as US speech.  Definitely, it's catching the technical terms  -  police procedure and drug-dealing  -  that's the problem.  And I'm sure a lot of southern Brits would struggle with Train Spotting without subtitles,

Comment: @Anixx, show me a language where changing one vowel in a word can't result in another word.  If that weren't so, the language would only need one vowel.

Comment: @David Garner British and Amerian speakers pronounce these words differently: Americans pronounce bet and bat similarly, British pronounce bat as Americans pronounce but, etc, due to English mess with vowels. Also, English has more such words, from the above lines, I can name only two Russian words from each: hor "choire" and "bit" "beaten", also "bit" as an information measure.

Comment: @Annix, I think it's time to close this discussion, which is getting silly.  Saying "English mess with vowels" is unhelpful.  You seem to imagine that there's a 'gold standard' of English pronunciation, which we've degraded, making it hard for us to understand our own language,

Comment: @Anixx and David Garner Would you mind moving this discussion to chat? I keep getting notifications to my answer, most of which are immaterial to my point.

Comment: @lemontree, apologies. I'm done with this post anyway, over and out.

Answer (score 3):

your America friends are having fun with you.  Nobody does this, unless they have hearing problems, the soundtrack is muddy, or they're in a noisy environment like a bar.  native speakers of American English are just people, no different than native speakers of any lsnguage.

as for spelling, it is complete irrelevant.  native speakers *never* need guidance from written language to disambiguate, in *any* language.

Comment: Nah, I have friends who do it, and I do it sometimes. It's certainly not necessary to understand what's being said, but I usually do it if I'm watching something on Netflix.

Comment: @sumelic: sure, but I dare say  they don't do it because they have trouble disambiguating vowels!

Comment: @sumelic: on the other hand there may be something there there. people who do not really need to do this, do it.  what does it all mean?!  it's not impossible that we are seeing some kind of basic shift in communication strategies.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is due to any linguistic phenomena, just a cultural thing.

I sometimes turn on the subtitles if I'm watching something on my computer using Netflix, but not if I'm watching on the TV or on Youtube. I believe  I picked up this habit from one of my friends; her family often turns the subtitles on so that they can pay more attention to other things while watching the TV.

In any case, nobody has subtitles when speaking to other people in real life or when listening to the radio, and American English speakers certainly do both of these things often without any trouble.

Subtitle's aren't really needed at all for disambiguating homophones, or even near homophones. Native speakers don't usually have any difficulty distinguishing different vowel sounds such as fit-feet, here-hair, bat-bet. I know these can be tough for non-native speakers, but to native speakers the differences are generally quite clear (barring drastic accent differences). The areas that I think are most likely to cause confusion or difficulty for native speakers listening to American English speech are vowel reduction and word division. Russian also has vowel reduction, and I believe word division is ambiguous in at least some cases in every spoken natural language.

Comment: "so that they can pay more attention to other things while watching the TV." - this is very strange because in all my understanding, it is the subtitles that need attention rather than voice.

Comment: @Anixx, Yeah, not sure how I'd explain how it helps. For example, you can talk more to other people while the TV's on. Also, subtitles are on the screen for longer than the words are being spoken.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it to be a matter of [phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonology). Regional dialects, accents and variations are very different in the English language. I think this problem occurs when one language covers different cultural regions (e.g. French and Spanish). I happen to notice the same complications in Arabic.